# How do I create a ParseQuery for an array of items?

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform, android-parsequeryadapter

I have a Game class which contains an Array of ParseUsers with the key "players":

```
@ParseClassName(Game.GAME)
public class Game extends ParseObject {
  public static final String PLAYERS = "players";

  public void addPlayer(ParseUser player) {
    addUnique(PLAYERS, player);
  }

  public List<ParseUser> getPlayers() {
    return getList(PLAYERS);
  }
}
```

The players have had a name field populated as follows:

```
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("name", name);
```

I want to get the names of these players and populate a ListView.  I am trying to figure out how to use ParseQueryAdapter to do this, but I can't figure out anything that either lets you do a ParseQuery that will select ParseUsers found in an array on Game or a way to turn a ParseQuery into a query of ParseUsers based on that array.  This is my best shot but I don't know how to select only the children of this query:

```
ListView playerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.player_list);
ParseQueryAdapter<ParseUser> adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseUser>(this,
    new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseUser>() {
  public ParseQuery create() {
    ParseQuery query = game.getQuery();
    query.include(Game.PLAYERS);
    return query;
  }
});
adapter.setTextKey("name");
playerListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

*Edit:* It's also important for me to preserve the order of the players in this Array.

Comment: Are there users who aren't game players?  If all users are players, then the desired query is equivalent to all users' names.

Comment: There are users that are not players in this particular Game instance, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something more like this. You need to query the player objects by some key value that sets them to a lobby or room to populate the list. This is not exactly how you would do it but the query would work similarly. I hope this helps. As far as loading into a list attribute im not sure this does the job though :/

```
ParseQueryAdapter<Post> mainAdapter;
ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Post> factory;
factory = new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Post>() {
                @Override
                public ParseQuery<Post> create() {
                    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("PlayerObject");
                    query.orderByDescending("CurrentLobby");
                    return query;
                }
            };
mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<Post>(this, factory) {
        @Override
        public View getItemView(final PlayerObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (v == null) {
                v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.player_item_on_list, null);
            }
            return v;
        }
    };
    mainAdapter.setPaginationEnabled(true);
    mainAdapter.setTextKey("title");
    mainAdapter.setImageKey("Image");
    mainAdapter.loadObjects();
```

Comment: So you're saying I need to add an entry for each game to the User object as well as an entry for each User to the game object?

It seems like I should be able to use the objectIds in the list stored in the Game object to find the users and not have to store the information in both directions.